# Geolocation in Java

Tags: java, geolocation, location, ip-address

I have some question regarding Geo-location to ask about.

**What is the different** if the lookupservice with and without 
    GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE | GEOIP_CHECK_CACHE  ?